# How does this gram-Schmidt process work for these two vectors. I keep doing something wrong.

Tags: linear-algebra

\begin{bmatrix}
    4       \\
    0        \\
   \
    3       & 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
    25       \\
    0        \\
   \
    -25       & 
\end{bmatrix}

for my solution, I end up getting [25,0,-25] - [4,0,3], for u2, the second vector. the first u1 vector I get right, but the second one doesn't make any sense... which are both 3x1 vectors. but the answer is actually

[image]

Comment: Why did you delete the previous version of this question, with answers already supplied?

Comment: You didn't normalize your vector. If you normalize it, you will obtain the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Your $\vec u_1$ is correct. For the second vector find:

$$
\vec u= \vec v_2-\langle v_2,u_1\rangle \vec u_1
$$
then normalize: $\vec u_2=\dfrac{\vec u}{||\vec u||}$

Comment: It is often simpler for computations to set $\,u=\vec v_2-\dfrac{\langle v_2,v_1\rangle}{\langle v_1,v_1\rangle}\vec v_1$ (i.e. *not* to use the normalised vectors previously found).